# Why in bootstrap when I minimize my window my <p> keeps getting longer and pushes all the content below it down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, paragraph

```
<div classs="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" style="background:black; padding:25px 0px;">content content</div>
</div>
<div class="span4 offset2">
    <p>blah blah blah this is a test blah blah blah this is a testblah blah blah this is a test <br />
       blah blah blah this is a testblah blah blah this is a testblah blah blah this is a test</p>
</div>
<div class="span12" style="blue; padding:25px 0px;">content content</div>
```

as I minimize the window the

will shrink in width but it will extend the paragraph down so it gets thinner and longer as the window minimizes it pushes ALL the content like the span12 at the bottom down. I want the

to NOT get longer as the window minimizes but maybe smaller or something. I tried removing the margin and padding from it but when I do that it will keep the content in the bottom of the

from being pushed down but the

literally still extends under the bottom span12 and creates a margin all the way at the bottom of the page. Can anyone tell me whats going on please.

**FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Lucaz5520/ZTgGX/ if you look at the paragraph as you minimize the window it will get thinner and push all the content below it down**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly certain where you want to go with this, but see if this helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/RkPED/

1: I've imported the Bootstrap responsive CSS,

2: changed the table width to `<table width="100%".....>` so that it doesn't conflict with the bootstrap grid on narrow screens, and

3: your grid divs weren't quite correct arround the last span12, I've noted the changes on the jsfiddle

Hope this helps!

Comment: the paragraph still gets longer.

Comment: Is the example @ http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/RkPED/ not what you are looking for @LucasSantos ? If it isn't, could you please clarify what you want to happen as the window narrows?

Comment: No it wasn't :/ it doesnt have to be a table in there it can be an image but picture a navigation bar on top and a footer bar in the bottom.. and in the middle a there is 2 span6 I guess you could say.. anyway to the right is the image and to the left is the paragraph.. now as you minimize the window the paragraph loses width and gains height and when it gains height it pushes all the content below it down such as the footer bar, i wnt it to not push the content down and remain the same height, maybe the letters could get smaller or the width remain the same just not gain height and push below

Comment: One option would be to use @media queries to decrease the font size as the window narrows. You would need to play with this though, depending on the specifics of your page. See the updated result and CSS @ http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/RkPED/

Comment: the media query doesn't seem to be working on the p tags.. I added the css to my <style type="text/css"> tags in my html

Comment: are the media queries working for you on the example I posted? If not, what browser are you using?

Comment: no there not.. im using Safari on my IMac (its pretty up to date)

Comment: For me on Safari and Chrome, the font size of the paragraph to the left of the table gets smaller as the window narrows, until 767px when the Bootstrap grid changes to its default of stacking spans one over the other. Maybe I don't understand what you are looking for.